# Change Style of Text Box Forms in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, forms

Is it possible to change the style of an field in LibreOffice?

The normal text field is shown as a "box", but I want it to look like a "line". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Text Box properties (double-click on control, tab "`General`")
2. Scroll down to "`Text type`"
3. Change from "`Multi-line`" to "`Single-line`":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tohuwawohu but thanks to your answer I know that I looked for the option "Border". I wanted it to have an option "Line" (but it only has "3D look", "Flat" and "None".)

Comment: OK :-) You may add an answer yourself and accept it so the question is marked as solved.